# Can I put the same line into the_content for Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, include

I want the same line of text added into all of my Wordpress articles.

The thing is that I do not want that same line of text at the beginning or end of my articles. Instead, I want it maybe after the 2nd paragraph?

Can I put some php include into the_content of all of my Wordpress articles and have it show up in the same place for all articles?

Answer (score 0):

You can just add read more in your article where you want the read more link to appear.

In your article, after second paragraph just add

```
<!--more-->
```

[Customizing the Read More](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More)

Alternatively you can trim the amount of words the content outputs with

```
wp_trim_words();
```

[wp_trim_words()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trim_words)

**EDIT:**

If you want to customize the output of `the_content()` then you can modify that function with the filter:

```
<?php

add_filter('the_content', 'my_custom_text', 11);

function my_custom_text($content) {    

    $content = ... ; //here you modify what your output is   
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: Sorry but not what I am looking for at all.

Comment: Then your question is not well put. You can output the 'read more' text (that doesn't have to be 'Read More' but some other string or html), after what ever line you wish. And if you want your articles on blog page have exactly 30 words then `wp_trim_words()` in which you put your `the_content()` (with or without read more) is the way to go...

Comment: No, my question is well put. I want the_content which spits out "this is my article right here" to spit out "this is my INSERT CRAP article right here". All the same within ALL articles but not including this customly, as I clearly explained above. I cannot add <!-- more --> and whatnot within the_content unless I open each article and customly add this in, as you are implying I do. "In your article, after second paragraph, just add...."

Comment: Wait, you do want, or don't want to show `the_content()` of your articles?